# What are master.000xxx in mysql data directory used for?

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of master.000xxx files in MySQL /data directory.

I'd like to know: what are they exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely binary logs:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html

These contain a record of every change to data (insert/update/delete) or metadata (create/alter/drop).

The binary log is what replicas download and use to replay the same changes in the same order.

You can also use binary log to do [point-in-time recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) after you restore a backup that notes the binary log position at the time of backup.

Comment: thx I think I had binary logs under another name in another system. I executed a purge and they disappeared...so, good!

Comment: As long as there were no replicas depending on them yes you can do that. You should also set a value for `expire_logs_days` in your MySQL config, so they purge themselves after a day or two.